# Storybook Navigation System

Tags: storybook

Is it possible to call different stories into different left sidebar menu groupings? For example: I have a Button story that I would like to call in two different navigation places.

Answer (score 0):

You can reimport a story from another files. A story is "just" a named exported function.

For example:

```js
// component1.stories.js

...

export const MyStory = ...
```

then:

```js
// component2.stories.js

export { MyStory } from './component1.stories.js';
```